# Number format in devextreme datagrid for Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme

In my dexextreme datagrid I'm using fixedPoint as the format for a cell with a number. The numbers are formatted like: 1,234,567.12
I want them to be formatted like 1.234.567,12
My feeling says it has something to do with the locale, but I'm not sure how to set it in my Angular2 application. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only thing you can do is to edit the numbers.js file in devextreme/localization. Ofcourse this is a horrific solution; an update of the package will break it, but it seems to be the only solution for now.